# Do not allow Purim Torah questions after Purim

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

Our current policy on [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) says

> Post Purim Torah questions between Rosh Chodesh Adar [Bet, if there is one] and a day or two after Purim, only<sup>1</sup>.

I would like to propose that only *answers* may be posted after *Purim* is over.  Questions should stop at the end of (Shushan?) *Purim*.  My proposed rewrite of this section is as follows:

> Post Purim Torah questions between Rosh Chodesh Adar [Bet, if there is one] and Shushan Purim, only (inclusive). Answers to Purim Torah questions may be posted until the questions are closed a day or two after Purim.

The reasons I think this makes more sense are as follows:

1. Questions that are posted two days after *Purim* do not have enough time to get answers.
2. The end of *Purim* itself is a less arbitrary time to end PTIJ season than a day or two afterwards.
3. There is a clear deadline for all PTIJ posts: the end of *Purim* for questions and when the particular question is closed for answers.

Answer (score 4):

While this makes some sense, I do not support it as the costs of implementing it far outweigh the benefits thereof IMHO. It's easier to explain to people that we have one time period with certain rules than to go about policing only questions for two days to a bunch of surprised and confused users.

If someone wants to post a question that late in the season, they do so at their own risk. If someone the next year wants to post an answer they can flag the question to be reopened.

Comment: This. Plus (and maybe I should post this as a separate answer), people think of good questions on Purim, don't have time to post them then, and want a chance to do so before next year. Or so I imagine, anyway.